# get view position from background activity and pass to overlay fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, overlay

I have created transparent fragment over an activity. This transparent fragment is working as a help to user to point particular view shown in background.

1. I want perfect x & y coordinates of view components from  background activity and pass them to transparent fragment using bundle. 
   and set position of arrow on fragment accordingly to point them dynamically regardless of phone or tablet screen size and resolution.
2. I am creating fragment from `onCreate()` method of an activity and I have already tried with `getX()`, `getY()`, `getLocationOnScreen()`,`getLocationOnWindow()`, `getTop()`, `getLeft()`,etc but all methods returns zero. so how can I get the coordinates of view placed in activity.
3. If user touch anywhere on fragment it should be destroy/detach. How can I achieve this? `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();`
   or replace with null anything is not working.
4. I want to disable background when fragment is created on activity. how I can do this?
   Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Just add some codes...

Comment: are you trying to build something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zL9rr.png) ?

Comment: Yes.. and I have almost try everything but could not get any solution even when calling view.getTop() method inside onWindowFocusChange()  @ Rahul Tiwari